# Show different date every 2 weeks

Tags: php, date

my first question is if this code will work?

And second is there a way to improve it, so it will every 2 weeks change the date without that I have to make new if statements?
If less than 20 june echo 20 june, if less than 4 july echo 4 july, etc.

```
if(date("d")<=20 && date("m")<=6){
    $text = '20 june';
}
else if(date("d")<=4 && date("m")<=7){
    $text = '4 july';
}
```

Comment: _my first question is if this code will work?_ - test it -.-

Comment: Regarding the first question - http://writecodeonline.com/php/ . About the second - don't have a clue about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Nothing complicated, I just want to show different date every 2 weeks.

Comment: The code will work just fine when looking at it swiftly. Also, since this is obviously an examn question, you should know it by yourself, not go online and ask here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My variant.

```
$StartDate = strtotime('2012-06-06'); //Start date from which we begin count
$CurDate = date("Y-m-d"); //Current date.
$NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", $StartDate)); //Next date = +2 week from start date
while ($CurDate > $NextDate ) { 
  $NextDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 week", strtotime($NextDate)));
}
echo date("d F", strtotime($NextDate)), "\n";
```

Comment: Agreed That's neater. :)

Comment: This works great. Its not for exams, but to make work easier.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. You basically want to slice the year into 2 week intervals. Each interval is represented by a date (in your case the date is the end of the 2 week period).

This, as you pointed out won't work at all. You would have no choice but to write if else conditions for the complete year.

What you can do instead is to maintain a $date variable as well.

```
//Initialize this part once on the first run of your code.
//Say you want to start on the 1st of June
$pivotDate = "2012-06-01";
```

Then what you want can be done by a simple condition to check each time the code runs:

```
$diff = abs(strtotime(date(c)) - strtotime($datePivot));
$days= floor($diff/(60*60*24));
if(days>14){
  $pivotDate=date(c);

}
```